# HTML tag in json object fails HTTP POST request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to make an HTTP POST request to a server (LeanKit API).

The HTTP request contains a JSON object, and one of the values is a string with `<br/>` tag.

I'm using Python's requests to make the HTTP request and this is the reply I get from the server:

> "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

When I take off the `<br/>` and replace it with `\n`, the new line is not showing when I check the result on the website.

I also tried using `\n\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n\r\n` and `\\n` etc.

This is how my POST request looks like:

```
r = requests.post("http://www.address.com", data=new_card_data, auth=('user@mail.com', 'password'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not really a Python problem. The *server* does not want to accept content with HTML tags in it.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an issue with the server not accepting html in a json object because it could potentially be malicious and tamper with or reveal server data.

If you want to make a new line in response to some json data, perhaps it would better to create your own new line identifier and store that in the JSON, and then create the HTML tag `<br />` based on that.

Maybe you could use something like "**\n**", and then check for that value in the json and generate a `<br />` in that case in the HTML.

Or you can do what @balintant said.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `<` and `>` characters to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.
It seems like your server cannot accept HTML tags.

Comment: I tried it already and then I just get a `<br/>` within the text.

Comment: @DavidTzoor then you can change the characters back. It is not a nice one, but it is a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the characters back?

Comment: @DavidTzoor Simply change `&lt;` and `&gt;` back to `<` and `>` on server side.